# How to get response based on the request body matching using wiremock and JSON

Tags: json, soap, mocking, wiremock

How to verify if my Soap request consists of an particular element in header and body using JSON and standalone WireMock.

I should get response1 if my request contain `<a:Id>1876</a:Id>` in the header else i should get response2

similarly i need to check in body also.

Below is my request XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:a="http://abc.example.com/a" 
xmlns:b="http://abc.example.com/b"
xmlns:c="http://abc.example.com/c"  
   <soapenv:Header>
      <a:abcHeaders>
         <a:Id>1876</a:Id>
         <a:Xid>12</a:Xid>
      </a:abcHeaders>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <b:abcOpern>
         <b:xyz>
            <c:pqr>12</c:pqr>
         </b:xyz>
      </b:abcOpern>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WireMock.Net you can use XPath matching. For some details see [here](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Stubbing-and-Request-Matching#xpath).